# Does a python Session instance explicitly need to be closed?

Tags: python, session, python-requests

Let's say I'm using a `requests.Session` instance to make API calls (rather than `requests.get(...)`).

If I do not explicitly call `.close()` on the session instance after finishing with the calls, is the connection left open indefinitely (and therefore wasting a connection), or does the session close automatically after a certain period of time?

```
import requests

def get_some_content():
    session = requests.Session()
    response_200 = session.get("https://httpbin.org/status/200")
    response_500 = session.get("https://httpbin.org/status/500")
    return response_200.content, response_500.content
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if that answers for you , or ask more in comments if you have more questions.

Answer (score 0):

Good question.In Standard Python It will be closed:

- When python GC garbage collected.
- Immediately after code becomes unreachable.

But  In JIT Python (PyPy) it will need to be closed

- Manually or it will keep opened for a while.

In repeated procedure calls , system will run out of open descriptors and will cause OS errors if limit is reached.

Best practice is to close after being used.

Ref : https://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/cpython_differences.html

> The garbage collectors used or implemented by PyPy are not based on reference counting, so the objects are not freed instantly when they are no longer reachable. The most obvious effect of this is that files (and sockets, etc) are not promptly closed when they go out of scope. For files that are opened for writing, data can be left sitting in their output buffers for a while, making the on-disk file appear empty or truncated. Moreover, you might reach your OS’s limit on the number of concurrently opened files.